# How to block laravel from setting session cookies (or any cookies) for specific routes?

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, laravel-4.2

We have some static pages that we are looking to cache. We still need them to go through Laravel 4.2.  However, if a person visits said page, I don't want any cookies to be sent from Laravel, including the session cookies.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` you are registering every route in `routes/web.php` under `web` middleware. Its the responsible for setting your session cookies.

You can register those routes in `routes/api.php` instead, or better yet, create another protected method in RouteServiceProvider to register those "cookieless" routes from another file, inside `/routes` folder.

**Laravel 4.***

For laravel 4.* you can change session configuration on each page you need without cookies. You gotta change these configs in `__construct`

class StatelessPageController extends BaseController {

```
public function __construct(Config $config)
{
    $config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    $config::set('cookie.driver', 'array');
}

public function statelessPage()
{
    return View::make('stateless.page', ['data' => 'value']);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, Laravel 4.2. I tagged it as such but could have highlighted it better.

Comment: @StackOverflowed just edited my reply with 4.2 example code.